# Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS - How to install RVM?

Tags: ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-10.04

These are the steps I have taken to install RVM:

1. Installing Ruby: `sudo apt-get install curl git-core ruby` the which ruby command works
2. Installing RVM:

   curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --rails --trace

My user is "loam" in the `/home/loam/.bashrc` I have added this to the **last line** of the file.

```
if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi

fi
```

And replaced `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` with `if [[ -n "$PS1" ]]; then`

When the RVM script was done I got the message:

```
* To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
```

And I did try it and got:

```
$ source /home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm
-sh: source: not found
```

`Which rvm` is **blank**.. I can see there is a .rvm folder in `/home/loam`

If I write:

```
$ $HOME
-sh: /home/loam: Permission denied
```

**Update:**
I have also tried the [Single-User Install Location: ~/.rvm/](https://rvm.io//rvm/install).. And stil which rvm is blank.

Comment: Did you try `sh source /home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm` ?

Comment: Just tried it: `sh: Can't open source`

Comment: Is `source` located in one of the directories in your $PATH variable?

Comment: What do you mean? `$ echo $HOME
/home/loam` I am sorry but I am new to ubuntu..

Comment: ooooh wow that's funny, little misunderstanding, maybe you don't have `source` in your $PATH variable is what I mean to say....

Comment: according to the link `source` is built-in, this link might help you out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20953/sudo-source-command-not-found

Comment: I tried the `sudo -s ` and then source command, but got the same result.

Comment: Try `/bin/bash -c source /home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: if `/bin/bash -c source /home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm` doesn't work, try `. /home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm`.

Comment: The first thing did not work. Here is the result of the secound: `# . /home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm
/home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm: 23: [[: not found
/home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm: 23: [[: not found
/home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm: 29: [[: not found
/home/loam/.rvm/scripts/rvm: 32: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
`

Comment: >>>_<<< I am new to ubuntu and I found out that bounce shell was loaded on login for my user instead of bash shell. This solved the problem with RVM, because the bash file got loaded..

Answer (score 0):

Use this instruction => https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ to set shell to `/bin/bash --login`